# How to compute an affine transformation of multiple points?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dot-product

I have a 3d numpy array of point (484,3,1) and a 2d transformation matrix (3,3). I want to compute the transformation for all 484 points.

I have tried to reshape the arrays and compute the dot product, but I am struggling to get it to output a (484,3,1) shaped array where all the points are transformed.

```
points = np.random.randint(0, 979, (484,3,1)) 
transformation = array([[0.94117647, 0.        , 0.        ],
                        [0.        , 0.94117647, 0.        ],
                        [0.        , 0.        , 1.        ]])

points.shape = (484,3,1)
transformation = (3,3)

transformation.dot(points).shape = (3,484,1)
```

I would like this to be as optimized as possible. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you get to your resulting shape? If you want a matrix multiplication (which I assume if looking at the output dimensions) the it should be `484,3,1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a reshape to `(484,3)` dimensions and use the `np.matmul` (`np.dot` is also possible but since you are looking for a matrix multiplication `matmul` is prefered according to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html)) product

```
np.matmul(points.reshape(484,-1), transformation).reshape(484,3,-1)
```

resulting shape is the same of course given by the last reshaping: `(484,3,1)`